# What am I doing wrong ? sed: -e expression #1, char 74: missing command

Tags: regex, sed

I am running Ubuntu 14 and am attempting to use sed to find a specific line in a file.

When I run the command

```
sed '/password\s[success=\d\sdefault=ignore]\spam_unix.so\sobscure\s+sha512/' testfile.txt
```

I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 74: missing command`

I am looking for the line:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: why not use grep?

Comment: Once you've found the line, what do you want to do with it? Sed commands consist of two parts: Where to do something, and what to do. Your code says where (`/.../`, the regex form of addressing), but not what (the *command* part).

Comment: BTW, `\s` is PCRE syntax for whitespace. It isn't guaranteed to be supported in BRE (which is what `sed` without extensions such as `-r` or `-E` uses; and even *with* those, all you're guaranteed is POSIX ERE regex syntax, which *also* doesn't promise `\s`). The portable way to write "any kind of whitespace" in a BRE or ERE regex is `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are forgetting to escape some characters that should be taken literally. Regex treats the brackets as a character class instead of literal characters, and the dot in the `pam_unix.so` should also be escaped. This is the regex that targets the string:

```
password(\s+)\[success=\d\sdefault=ignore\](\s+)pam_unix\.so\sobscure(\s+)sha512
```

If you put it into the command it would look like this:

```
sed '/password(\s+)\[success=\d\sdefault=ignore\](\s+)pam_unix\.so\sobscure(\s+)sha512/' testfile.txt
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/IUuzbO/2) is a link to the regex I used

Comment: This not only doesn't answer the question (the error the OP is experiencing is because no command is given, and this answer duplicates that error), it is also incorrect.  When using basic regular expressions (which sed does if you do not invoke it with `-E`), `[` and `]` match literally, while `\[` and `\]` denote a character class.

Answer (score 3):

You miss a command. Try to add jus character p at the end:

```
sed /password\s[success=\d\sdefault=ignore]\spam_unix.so\sobscure\s+sha512/p' testfile.txt
```

If you use regex in some programming language, usually you need to write pattern and use it by some another method from the library. Tools like sed or awk expected with a pattern also an information about what you want to do with this pattern. Fx:

- /p print passed strings
- /s replace strings

Comment: You'll want to add the `-n` option if the goal is to *only* print matching lines.